# Python - ccsselect with spaces

Tags: python, html, css, lxml

I use lxml for parsing html files in Python.

And I use cssselect.
Something like that:

```
from lxml.html import parse

page = parse('http://.../').getroot()
img = page.cssselect('div.photo cover div.outer a') # problem
```

But I have a problem. There are spaces in class-names in HTML:

```
<div class="photo cover"><div class=outer>
<a href=...
```

Without them everything is ok. How can I parse it (I can't edit html code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `div` with `photo` and `cover` class, use `div.photo.cover`.

```
img = page.cssselect('div.photo.cover div.outer a')
```

Instead of thinkg `class="photo cover"` as class attribute with `photo cover` as a value, think it as a class attribute with `photo` and `cover` as values.